# How do I open a file from Android's "external" storage, read that picture into a bitmap object, and return

Tags: c#, bitmap, android-camera2

I am using the camera2 api in Android to capture an image and save it to my phone in "external" storage. I put external in quotations because even though Android names the storage external the storage place is still located on the phone and not an SD card or a physical external storage device. However the next step in my project is to store the image I just captured into the Microsoft SQL Server Database. I am attempting to convert the image into a bitmap so that way it can be stored in the database.

I have tried using this code below but it has several flaws. I am hard-coding the file size(which isn't even the accurate file size) and I am reading in the bytes from the picture but not storing them in a bitmap object.

public System.IO.Stream GetPictureFromFile()
        {

```
        try
        {
            var file = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/RAW_2019_01_24_16_55_11_638.dng");
            System.IO.Stream openStream = System.IO.File.Open(file.AbsolutePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);



            System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("/storage/emulated/0/image.dng");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)//Replace Hardcoded filelength
            {
                fs.WriteByte((byte)openStream.ReadByte());
            }



            openStream = Assets.Open("/storage/emulated/0/image.dng");
            openStream.Close();

            return openStream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

This code fails when trying to open the newly created "image.dng" and save it in the "openStream" stream object. I would like to find a way to avoid using the openStream object and store the data directly into a bitmap object.

Comment: To begin with, you must provide one of predefined string constants to [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) , e.g. `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`. This will give you the path to the file, see the code snippet at the link.